# Getting database field value not working

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access

I am using the ado connection a adoquery and dsr and adotable

I have a database with bookingnumbers as a field in the table client.

I would like to get the last bookingnumber in the field and store it in a variable.

The booking number is saved as text on access.

So far I have:

```
Var
sNum : string;
....
sNum := Datamodule1.tblClient['BookingNumber'].Last;
```

but it is not working.

please help?

Comment: If your `Last` is supposed to go to the final record in the dataset, you can't do it like that.  It would be easier to use a custom Sql statement, like 'SELECT MAX(BookingNumber) FROM CLIENT' if CLIENT is the name of your table.

Comment: What you are attempting to do will fail in concurrent situations, what if you have 2 clients that execute a request at the same moment? They will get the same booking number and this will result in duplicate records. Let the database generate the number for you (use an autoinc field, sequence, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a good idea to try and find the maximum value of a field by navigating the dataset, especially if the dataset isn't necessarily ordered by the field in question.  Try something like this instead:

```
function TForm1.GetMaxBookingNumber : Integer;
var
  Q : TAdoQuery;
begin
  Q := TAdoQuery.Create(Nil);
  Q.Connection := DataModule1.AdoConnection1;  //  or whatever the name of your connection is
  try
    Q.SQL.Text := 'SELECT MAX(BookingNumber) FROM CLIENT';
    Q.Open;
    // the `not IsNull` in the following allows for the table being empty
    if not Q.Fields[0].IsNull then 
      Result := Q.Fields[0].AsInteger
    else
      Result := -1;
  finally
    Q.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: undeclared identifier 'TAdoQuery'

Comment: is there something i should add in the uses

Comment: You said in your Q that you had Ado components in your project already ("i am using the ado connection a adoquery and dsr and adotable").  If you don't, add ADODb to your uses list.

Answer (score -1):

So here is what i wanted :
var 
sNum : string;
procedure button click
begin

with Datamodule1 do
    begin
      qryClient.SQL.Add('SELECT BookingNumber FROM Client');
      qryClient.Open;
      qryClient.last;
      sNum := qryClient['BookingNumber'];
    end;
end;